# Two spacecraft leaving earth-Doppler relativistic effect

Tags: physics, general-relativity, special-relativity

I recently begun approaching special and general relativity. I found this problem in my book and I'm trying to solve it but I'm finding some difficulties:

An observer on Earth sees two twins A and B, in two different spacecrafts, leaving in opposite directions, both with
velocities $\beta=0.5$. After a time $\Delta t$, the observer on Earth sends a message to the twin A using an energy photon $E_0=hV_0$. When A receives it, it decides to send it also to the B so that it knows the information, and it does so by sending another photon with the same energy with which it has detected it. I have to find:
The frequency with which A receives the photon and also the frequency with which B receives the photon from A.
If, instead of photons,I send a mass particle $m$ with which energy the first twin A receives the particle? And with which energy the second twin B receives the particle from A?

I know that this involve the well known relativistic Doppler effect and I'm trying to use the relation: $\nu=\nu'\sqrt{\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}}$ however I can't understand how I can use it to find the frequency with which B receives photon from A.
Moreover in the second part when I have no idea of which relationship I have to use

Comment: What is the relative speed of A and B according to them?

Comment: @md2perpe Ionly have this information about the velocities.

Comment: You are supposed to have an equation about how velocities add to get the speeds that A sees B at.  It is called the velocity addition law, as I recall.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think that I can use Lorentz transormation but I'm not sure

Comment: The law is derived from that.

Comment: @RossMillikan Honestly I understand that I have to use it but when I calculate de final frequency, the result is not acetable. I don't know where is my error...

Comment: You also have the information "leaving in opposite directions" which implies that their velocities are parallel (or should I write "anti-parallel" since they are in opposite, not same, direction). Their relative speed, according to themself, is therefore give by the ordinary speed addition formula; it's (0.5+0.5)/(1+0.5*0.5). Use this information when you calculate the frequency that B gets.

Comment: Unless you show your work we can't tell what is wrong